# Copy the respective values from another workbook depend on specific conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

With following to this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75181219/get-the-respective-values-of-the-latest-closing-date)
, I need to match the values found in `wb1.coumns(1)` with the other workbook `wb2.coumns(1)` with some particular conditions. 
Wb2 will be filtered with the value `Close` at column 13 `M`. 
**My question**: is to seek the Wb2 (the open workbook) **Latest closing Date** on column 11 `K` and then copy the respective values at columns (“B, and “Q:X”) (on the same row ), 
Then paste these values in Wb1.columns (“S:AA”) respectively. 
The below code designed to returns back with the respective values of only one column of wb2 (column “B”) 
This is the [Link](https://easyupload.io/500rdf) for test workbooks.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub Get_Respective_Values_Of_Last_Closing_Date()
 
   Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
   Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant
   Dim dict As New Dictionary
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
   Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
   Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Book_B.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
 
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
 
     Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A3:AA" & ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)  'Main Range
     Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A3:X" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)   'Opened Workbook_Range
 
      arr1 = rng1.Value2
      arr2 = rng2.Value2
 
     'place the unique last key in a dictionary:
     Dim i As Long
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
        If arr2(i, 13) = "Close" Then   'Column (Status)
            If Not dict.Exists(arr2(i, 1)) Then
                dict(arr2(i, 1)) = Array(arr2(i, 2), arr2(i, 11))       'Place the _Date_ from K:K, too
            Else
                If CDate(arr2(i, 11)) > CDate(dict(arr2(i, 1))(1)) Then 'Change the item only in case of a more recent _Date_:
                    dict(arr2(i, 1)) = Array(arr2(i, 2), arr2(i, 11))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
 
    'Place the necessary data in its place:
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If dict.Exists(arr1(i, 1)) Then
            arr1(i, 19) = dict(arr1(i, 1))(0) 'extract first item array element
        Else
            arr1(i, 19) = "NA"
        End If
    Next i
 
    rng1.Value2 = arr1 'drop back the updated array content
 
    ws1.Activate
 
'   wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox "Ready..."
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I correctly understood the question... Please, clarify the next aspects: 1. What do you mean by "seek the Latest closing Date on column 11 K and then copy the respective values at columns (“B, and “Q:Z”) (on the same row )"? To paste **the latest closing Date** in the workbook **where it has been found (`wb2`)** (“B, and “Q:Z”)? The data from "B:B" does not count, anymore? 2. What "paste these values in Wb1.columns (“S:AA”) respectively" should mean? Which **these values** to be pasted? The latest found closing Date, or the value from "B:B", if it still means something?

Comment: *“B, and “Q:Z”* is 11 columns, while *“S:AA”* is only 9.

Comment: @FaneDuru , It is nearly the same linked question, But I need to return more values from `wb2` depends on the status of `Close` and the `Latest closing date`
Please see these Pictures to more clarification https://ibb.co/FJZ910D   and  https://ibb.co/J5VJ826

Comment: @VBasic2008 ,“B, and “Q:Z” is 9 columns and not 11

Comment: In which alphabet? `B,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z`. Maybe you need *"Q:AA"* or *"S:AC"*.

Comment: @VBasic2008 , I am so sorry (my bad) . I was mean columns `“B”` and `”Q:X”` at wb2. I edited the question

Comment: @FaneDuru , I am so sorry . I was mean columns `“B”` and `”Q:X”` at wb2. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next updated code:

```
Sub Get_Respective_Values_Of_Last_Closing_Date()

   Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
   Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant
   Dim dict As New Dictionary
   
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
   Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Book_B.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
   
     Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A3:AA" & ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)  'Main Range
     Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A3:X" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)    'Opened Workbook_Range

      arr1 = rng1.Value2
      arr2 = rng2.Value2

     'place the unique last key in a dictionary:
     Dim i As Long, arrAtt, j As Long, k As Long
     ReDim arrAtt(7) 'the 1D array should contain maximum number of elements from "Q" to "X"
                     'meaning 8 columns. since arrAtt is 1D zero based, it may keep 8 elements
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
        If arr2(i, 13) = "Close" Then           'Column (Status)
            Erase arrAtt: ReDim arrAtt(7)       'erase the previous loaded array, if the case (to be loaded...)
            If Not dict.Exists(arr2(i, 1)) Then
                For j = 0 To UBound(arrAtt)     'iterate between the 8 array elements
                    If arr2(i, 17 + j) <> "" Then
                        arrAtt(k) = arr2(i, 17 + k): k = k + 1 'add the found URLs and increment k
                    Else
                        Exit For                               'exit the iteration if no URL exists
                    End If
                Next j
                If k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrAtt(k - 1)     'keep only the loaded elements
                dict(arr2(i, 1)) = Array(arr2(i, 2), arr2(i, 11), arrAtt)   'Place attachments array, too
                k = 0 'reinitialize k variable
            Else
                If CDate(arr2(i, 11)) > CDate(dict(arr2(i, 1))(1)) Then 'Change the item only in case of a more recent  Date
                    Erase arrAtt: ReDim arrAtt(7) 'erase the previous loaded array
                    For j = 0 To UBound(arrAtt)
                    If arr2(i, 17 + j) <> "" Then
                        arrAtt(k) = arr2(i, 17 + k): k = k + 1
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrAtt(k - 1)
                dict(arr2(i, 1)) = Array(arr2(i, 2), arr2(i, 11), arrAtt)     'Place attachments array, too
                k = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'Place the necessary data in its place:
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        If dict.Exists(arr1(i, 1)) Then
            arr1(i, 19) = dict(arr1(i, 1))(0) 'extract first item array element
            For j = 0 To UBound(dict(arr1(i, 1))(2))          'extract existing URLs
                If dict(arr1(i, 1))(2)(j) = "" Then Exit For  'exit the loop in case of empty strings
                arr1(i, 20 + j) = dict(arr1(i, 1))(2)(j)      'place the URLs in their position
            Next j
        Else
            arr1(i, 19) = "NA"
        End If
    Next i
    
    rng1.Value2 = arr1 'drop back the updated array content
    
    ws1.Activate
    
'   wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox "Ready..."
   
End Sub
```

But, if you intend to adapt `wb2` workbook in terms of clearing some URLs (for the latest closing Date) , the code should be adapted to preliminarily clear the range "S:AA" in `wb1` till the end of the sheet. Otherwise, existing URLs may remain from the previous run

Comment: @Waleed Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/1b6spm) the updated workbook.

Comment: I tried a quick test and found it works perfectly.
Please could you add more comments on the code itself to fully understand it.
I do not understand some points, like `ReDim arrAtt(7)` and why  it is specifically **7** ?

Comment: @Waleed OK. I will place some more comments.

Comment: Please , Do you have interest on this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373080/saveas-a-file-and-move-it-s-icon-to-the-same-old-position-of-the-original-file-o) , if not , please tell me to start a bounty (although i am not sure it can help)

Comment: @Waleed It is really complicated and I do not have availability for the next days. If I will be available, if i will finish rapider what I have to finish, I will maybe try to spend some time to see what is it about. But this cannot be considered a promis...