# SaveAs a file and move it’s icon on Desktop to the same old position of the original file

Tags: excel, vba, automation, desktop, windows-scripting

I have used the below code to  a workbook (SaveAs) and then delete the original file. 
The Windows OS put the new created file on the first left vacant space on My Desktop. 
What I need after using `SaveAs` , is to move it’s icon to the same old position of the original file on my Desktop. 
Meaning, If my file is initially placed on the upper right of my desktop , I want to keep it in that location after using SaveAs. 
In advance, appreciate for your time to help.

```
Sub Rename_Me_Automatic()
 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
    Dim FilePath As String, wb As Workbook, FolderPath As String
    Dim oldName As String, newName As String
 
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     FilePath = wb.FullName
      FolderPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
       oldName = wb.Name
 
     newName = Left(oldName, Len(oldName) - 5) & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 20)
 
     wb.SaveAs FolderPath & newName
 
     Kill FilePath   'delete orginal file
 
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it can be possible, but this looks to be a  whole big project...

Comment: Did you try to `save-as` with the original file name which will just overwrite the old file and then only rename it instead of deleting?

Comment: It was a very good suggestion and I also could swear that it will work... Starting from observation that when you change the name of a file (even on Desktop), it does not move. It should be, probably, a matter of  naming way. We should completely imitate the way Windows works. Probably using Shell32 or DOS commands... I will look to your code and try dapapting it...

Comment: @FaneDuru , yes I realized that it is a matter of `Rename` issue. In fact I prepare a question to ask about all the possible methods to `rename a file` ( including FSO , DOS, PowerShell , etc….) using VBA language.

Comment: Did you test the answer code I supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, also try this code. It uses classical Windows behavior. VBA writes a VBScript, creates the file and runs it. The script finds the open Excel session, the workbook in discussion, save, close it, quits Excel application in certaing circumstances and changes the workbook name only after that (keeping the same file icon position). Finally, the script kills itself:

```
Sub SaveAndChangeActiveWorkbookName_VBScript()
     Dim vbsStr As String, fso As Object, vbsObj As Object, strVBSPath As String
     Dim newName As String, wb As Workbook, ext As String, searchName As String
     
     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     With wb
        ext = Split(.Name, ".")(UBound(Split(.Name, ".")))
        searchName = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - (Len(ext) + 1))
     End With
     
     newName = searchName & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 20) & "." & ext
     
     strVBSPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Rename.vbs" 'the fullname of the VBScript to be created and run
     
     vbsStr = "Dim objExcel, wb, objFile, FSO, fullName" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set objExcel = GetObject(, ""Excel.Application"")" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set FSO = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")" & vbCrLf & _
            " Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks(""" & ThisWorkbook.Name & """)" & vbCrLf & _
            "fullName = wb.FullName" & vbCrLf & _
            "wb.Close True" & vbCrLf & _
            "If objExcel.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then" & vbCrLf & _
            "   objExcel.Quit" & vbCrLf & _
            "ElseIf objExcel.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then" & vbCrLf & _
            "    If not UCase(Workbooks(1).Name) = ""PERSONAL.XLSB"" Then" & vbCrLf & _
            "         objExcel.Quit" & vbCrLf & _
            "    End If" & vbCrLf & _
            "End If" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(fullName)" & vbCrLf & _
            "objFile.Name = """ & newName & """" & vbCrLf & _
            "FSO.DeleteFile Wscript.ScriptFullName, True" 'kill itself...
                        
     Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set vbsObj = fso.OpenTextFile(strVBSPath, 2, True)
            vbsObj.Write vbsStr 'write the above string in the VBScript file
     vbsObj.Close
      
      Shell "cmd.exe /c """ & strVBSPath & """", 0  'execute/run the VBScript
End Sub
```

The next version tries simplifying your code, not needing any API:

```
Sub SaveAndChangeActiveWorkbookName_ShellAppl()
   Dim sh32 As Object, oFolder As Object, oFolderItem As Object, wb As Workbook
   Dim newName As String, ext As String, searchName As String
   
   Set sh32 = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   
   With wb
     ext = Split(.Name, ".")(UBound(Split(.Name, ".")))            'extract extension
     searchName = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - (Len(ext) + 1)) 'extract the rest of its name
     
     newName = searchName & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 20) & _
                                                                        IIf(showExtension, "." & ext, "") 'it sets correct new name...

     .Save
     .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly '!
     
     Set oFolder = sh32.Namespace(.Path & "\")
     Set oFolderItem = oFolder.ParseName(.Name)
     oFolderItem.Name = newName
     
     If (UCase(Workbooks(1).Name) = "PERSONAL.XLSB" _
            And Workbooks.Count = 2) Or Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
         Application.Quit
     Else
        .Close False 'no need to save it again and it closes faster in this way...
     End If
   End With
End Sub

'Function to check how 'Hide extension for known file type' is set:
Function showExtension() As Boolean
   Dim fileExt As String, Shl As Object, hideExt As Long
   
   fileExt = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\HideFileExt"
   Set Shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   hideExt = Shl.RegRead(fileExt)
   If hideExt = 0 Then showExtension = True
End Function
```

I've been educated that Windows does not allow changing name of an open workbook. Which is true, you cannot do it manually. Windows does not let you do it, this is its philosophy to avoid data loss.

But setting `ReadOnly` file attribute looks to temporarily remove the file full name from the Windows File Allocation Table. If you try `Debug.Print wb.FullFileName` before and after changing its attribute, it will show the same (old) one. But it looks that there are ways to do it and letting the open workbook outside the Allocation Table, you can change its name. I did not even imagine this is possible and I consider that this is the most important issue I learned today.

Comment: The `VBScript()` sub works perfectly as I need. **But**, the second code has two issues:(1) the workbook has been renamed but the position of its icon on desktop changed from the original file,
(2) the new name of the workbook contains the string `.xlsm` ( it is plus the extension itself .xlsm)

Comment: Also, I like to tell you that `VBScript()` sub in addition it works perfectly, it does not cause any flickering on the screen  (my code do flickering).
Please, if you can adapt `VBScript()` to exit excel session if no other workbook still open , I tried to use   `If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
          Application.Quit
      Else
          ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
      End If` But it does not work. (If succeeded then your answer deserves full acceptance)

Comment: @Waleed I am not at home now, but I will there be soon. Both requirements/problems are solvable...

Comment: @Waleed I've just opened my laptop. I will easily adapt the VBScript version and I will try understanding what's happening in the Shell version. I tested it and it did the job as it should. I did not tested in the appropriate environment to also `Quit` the application. (Now) I cannot understand the issue of double extension...

Comment: @Waleed Please, test the updated versions. Now, I will delete my previous pseudo answer which tried stating that you cannot change the name of an open workbook. I only kept it until you should read my last comment...

Comment: Now, with `Sub..VBScript()` I got this error `Subscript out of range Code` as this screenshot [Link](https://ibb.co/QM2B9bk) and there is file created on my desktop with name `Rename.vbs` [Link](https://easyupload.io/27wai7).
For the other `Sub… ShellAppl()` the two mentioned issues earlier on my comment still as it is. Kindly, may I ask: Why you do not use `FileSystemObject.GetBaseName(filePath)` to get the extension ?

Comment: @Waleed It looks you don not have/use "PERSONAL.XLSB"? Then, trying `objExcel.Workbooks(1).Name` when no workbook is open raises the error. I will adapt it to do it in a second phase.  About second question, I never use another object if it is not necessary. May I connect to your computer to see what's happening in your installation? But after I will adapt the VBScript version and you confirm that it works...

Comment: @Waleed Adapted the VBScript version to work with or without "PERSONAL.XLSB". Without it, that code sequence should be much simpler....

Comment: Now, `Sub..VBScript()` works perfectly as I needed exactly , In fact it’s enough for me. (accepted answer and bounty)

Comment: @Waleed But if you want debugging the second version, which works as it should in my installation, I am available for the next 20 minutes to connect. It is good to enlarge your orizont, I think.... Understanding why a piece of code does not work is better for learning than looking to a working piece of code, in my opinion.

Comment: I am now at my work, may be today evening I will test on my laptop and if the issue still exists, I will let you know.

Comment: I tried now on my laptop the the second version: I found it works as expected except one thing **(The double extension)** ! , I even tried to replace your line code of `ext = Split(.Name, ".")(UBound(Split(.Name, ".")))` with `ext = fso.GetExtensionName(filePath)` But the same issue. this issue disappear if **File name extension** is enabled on OS

Comment: @Waleed Well, I always uncheck `Hide extensions for known file types`. I always felt the need to **see** extensions... But I must confess that I did not know that (and never could check because of this setting) that it is possible to change only the **visible** name, keeping its existing extension. I know how to check (even change its value) a specific Registry key to see the respective setting. I am asking myself if having this setting as Windows default it only changes only the name. If so, I can easily create a function to return `True`/`False` and change the new name accordingly...

Comment: @Waleed For now, I adapted the code to check the above mentioned Registry key and build the new name with or without extension, according to `showExtension` function return. Theoretically, it should work as you need in both cases. If you test it in both circumstances (hide or unhide extensions) and it does not do what you need/what I think it should do, I will try connecting. If it works as it should, both of us learned something and no need for any connection...

Comment: I tried the second version (Latest updated) in both cases and now all works perfectly as intended. **I am grateful for all your help** and I am really **happy** because I post such a question 

Comment: @Waleed Now, only from curiosity: You really need such a scenario, or only wanted to see if/how it is possible?

Comment: Surly , I needed it. Because my desktop has a lot of file icons and my eye are customized with the location of each file on desktop. before this question, when my VBA macros do it's task and at last step `SaveAS` , I found my workbooks changed it's positions on desktop and I had to drag them manually to their old place

Comment: @Waleed Anyhow, the new name may become kilometric, with the actual naming algorithm... Don't you need to have a constant literal root to which a numeric random part to be added? This is what I thought you try doing and that's why I thought that the workaround proposed in my first answer should be acceptable...

Comment: I just used `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 20)` only for a testing purpose on this question, But in my actual environment, I have a another function to handle the new name as per my requirements.

Comment: @Waleed OK. I wish you a good night!

Answer (score 1):

**Intro**: 
 Windows OS saves the positions of desktop icons somewhere in registry or another location. 
When I post my question, I thought the answer will depend on extracting coordinates of (SavedAs workbook icon) on my desktop, 
And then using an API method to place it on the old location of the original file. 
**But** , It looks hard for VBA programmers. 
  
So, I tried the idea of @Daniel Dušek : 
(The idea was to `SaveAs` with the original file name which will just overwrite the old file and then rename it instead of deleting). 
The idea itself is excellent, But using native VBA methods (`Name` and `FileSystemObject. MoveFile`) , 
have a possible behavior to move the file beside renaming and I need to imitate how Windows OS works when it rename a file (like when you use right-click and choose Rename), 
and also, I cannot rename the open workbook by using (Name and FSO. MoveFile) even after set `ChangeFileAccess to xlReadOnly`.  
**But,** with using native OS API , you can do much more than  you can imagine. 
I have got a sophisticated API to `Rename` [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412333/how-to-rename-a-workbook-other-than-using-name-and-filesystemobject-movefile) by the **professional** @Siddharth Rout 
The advantage of this API is you can rename a workbook **while it is still open** (sure after Change File Access to xlReadOnly) .  
Now, All works correctly as expected, and I can SaveAs a file keep it’s icon on desktop at the same old position of the original file.

```
Sub SaveAs_and_Rename_Me_Automatically()
 
    Dim wb As Workbook, filePath As String, folderPath As String
    Dim oldName As String, newName As String, ext As String
    Dim fso As Object
 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     filePath = wb.FullName
      folderPath = wb.Path & "\"
       oldName = fso.GetBaseName(filePath)
        ext = fso.GetExtensionName(filePath)
          newName = oldName & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 20) & "." & ext
 
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
     wb.SaveAs folderPath & oldName              'SaveAs with orginal name (just overwrite)
 
     wb.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly              'change file access to Read_Only:
 
     SHRenameFile filePath, folderPath & newName  'to rename the Workbook while it is still open!
 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
      If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
          Application.Quit
      Else
          ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
      End If
End Sub
```

**And this the great API to rename:**

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" _
        Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As LongPtr
 
Private Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = &H100
Private Const FO_RENAME = &H4
 
Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As LongPtr
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAborted As Boolean
    hNameMaps As LongPtr
    sProgress As String
End Type
 
Public Sub SHRenameFile(ByVal strSource As String, ByVal strTarget As String)
 
    Dim op As SHFILEOPSTRUCT
 
    With op
        .wFunc = FO_RENAME
        .pTo = strTarget
        .pFrom = strSource
        .fFlags = FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS
    End With
 
    SHFileOperation op   '~~> Perform operation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not say anything...

I have something to do in the next time interval, so I prepared a workaround, but working code based on my comment to your answer assumption, respectively:

1. A workbook named as the one keeping the code, only having a different numeric suffix before its extension, must exist on Desktop, like reference for the place where the other workbook to be placed;
2. Your code creates a new workbook, with a random (new) suffix.
3. `ThisWorkbook` is saved overwriting the existing workbook on Desktop, but using `SaveCopyAs`, to let the original workbook open and the overwitted workbook to be renamed (not being open):

```
Private Sub testSaveCopyAsOverwrite()
   'References:
   'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation '(C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll)
   Dim oShell  As Shell32.Shell, oFolder As Shell32.Folder, oFolderItem As Shell32.FolderItem
   Dim filePath As String, initFileName As String, newFileName As String, wb As Workbook
   Dim thisName As String, newName As String, ext As String, searchName As String
   
   filePath = "C:\Users\Fane Branesti\OneDrive\Desktop\"
   
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    thisName = wb.name
    ext = Split(thisName, ".")(UBound(Split(thisName, ".")))
    searchName = left(thisName, Len(thisName) - (Len(ext) + 1))
    
RecreateName: 'for the case when RandBetween returns the same name suffix...
    newName = searchName & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 20) & "." & ext
    
   Set oShell = New Shell32.Shell
   
   initFileName = Dir(filePath & searchName & "*." & ext)  'find the file to be overwriten
   If initFileName <> "" Then
        If newName = initFileName Then GoTo RecreateName 'if RandBetween returned the same suffix...
   
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=filePath & initFileName 'overwrite the existing workbook, but keeping the original wb open
        
        Set oFolder = oShell.NameSpace(filePath)
        Set oFolderItem = oFolder.ParseName(initFileName)
        oFolderItem.name = newName 'change the initial file name with the necessary one, without moving it!
   Else
       MsgBox "No any workbook having the name pattern as: """ & filePath & searchName & """*." & ext & """"
   End If
End Sub
```

Please, take care to add the required reference (from C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll) before running it...

In fact, you can run the next code to add it:

```
Sub addShellControlsAndAutomation()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  On Error Resume Next
   Application.vbE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll"
   If err.number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation' reference already added...", vbInformation, _
               "Reference already existing"
   End If
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I got `Run-time error 1004: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Test1.xlsm'` @ this line `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=filePath & initFileName`.
And surly, I changed `filePath` to my environment.

Comment: @Waleed Does your `filePath` end in backslash "\"? If it does, what `initFileName` displays moving the cursor over it, when stopped on error? I mean, is it what you need (a workbook with the name you expect)? Of course, supposing that the workbook you test (keeping the code) is  named as "Test.xlsm"... Of course, "Test1.xlsm" **must NOT be open**... Are you at the office? May I connect to your computer?

Comment: `filePath` end in a backslash “\” and found out `initFileName` is the same as original name “Test.xlsm”

Comment: I start with manually renmaing my file with name `Test` , to eliminate any confusion

Comment: @Waleed if the file in discussion is NOT open, such an error cannot be raised... You did not say anything about the issue. Is it possible to crush Excel and a session remained open, even not visible keeping the file in discussion open? Can you manually change its name? So, can I connect to your computer? I am sure that I can show what is missing for the code to run.

Comment: The file in discussion is **Open**. I cannot manually rename it after I received the cited error .It is not available to connect to my PC (IT restriction).
BTW, my provided answer is **wiki** ,you can edit if you like. Also in my answer I used `wb.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly`

Comment: @Waleed No need of any other question, which as it is formulated will record only down votes. Then, if the file is open this only proves that you did not understand my answer code and you did not correctly reproduce it.  Why should I edit some code which I  do not understand what it is trying to do? I asked you specifically ("how could you rename an open workbook"), but you did not say anything. I am not used to work in such conditions, sorry. If you are not able to test a piece of code, created only for you, I do not need it at all and want something I cannot also understand, I cannot help...

Comment: @Waleed I would only like to confirm that my above code **is tested and it does what I explained it does**. How to modify the name of an open workbook? **Why is it open**? If you really need help, please try understanding my code... And about your newly useless question, it is in my code **a tested way** of changing the file name **without moving its icon position on Desktop**. Only posting questions to gain notoriety voting them up from the other account is not a fair way of doing that.

Comment: And I can confirm for you that I have tried your code exactly as it is (I just changed `filePath` to = "D:\Users\MyName\Desktop\"`) and it did not work and produced **the Run-time error '1004**.
And about my useless question (thank you !!) ,

Comment: @Waleed May I see now, when probably you are at home, how did you test the code. I can guaranty that it will work as you need...

Comment: I am using now my laptop, I will send Team-viewer ID and Password to your yahoo email.

Comment: I have sent team-viewer credentials to your email. I tried your code on my laptop and it is the same problem  `Run-time error 1004: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file`

Comment: I try connecting now...

Comment: Connection has been interrupted...

Comment: do you have AnyDesk installed? TeamViwer need licence...

Answer (score 0):

a bit hacky setup but works, the idea is following:

1. save workbook with the suffix "to_del"
2. from that temp file we rename the original file
3. save the workbook as the renamed file
4. delete "to_del" file from the original file

the code:

```vb
Sub Rename_Me_Automatic()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim filePath As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim oldName As String
Dim newName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
filePath = wb.FullName
folderPath = wb.path & Application.PathSeparator
oldName = wb.Name
newName = Left(oldName, Len(oldName) - 5) & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 20)
wb.SaveAs Filename:=folderPath & newName & "_to_del.xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Name folderPath & oldName As folderPath & newName & ".xlsm"
wb.SaveAs Filename:=folderPath & newName & ".xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Kill folderPath & newName & "_to_del.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work as my need,  the workbook has been renamed but the position of its icon on desktop changed from the original file. Anyhow, I found the answer for my question and I posted it.