# How to rename a workbook other than using (Name) and (FileSystemObject. MoveFile)?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, file-rename, windows-scripting

Suppose I have a workbook on my desktop with name `Test.xlsm` and I need to rename it to `Test2.xlsm` in the same path. 
I can rename it using **Name** statement as the following :

```
Sub Rename_using_Name()
 
    Dim oldName As String, newName As String
 
    oldName = "D:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test.xlsm"
    newName = "D:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test2.xlsm"
 
    Name oldName As newName
 
End Sub
```

Or, I can rename using **FileSystemObject** , like the following:

```
Sub Rename_using_FileSystemObject()
 
   Dim fso As Object, oldName As String, newName As String
 
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
   oldName = "D:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test.xlsm"
   newName = "D:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test2.xlsm"
 
   fso.MoveFile oldName, newName
 
End Sub
```

I seek for any additional means to rename a workbook other than the above cited ones. 
In advance, great thanks for all your help.

Comment: Might we ask why?

Comment: Both methods uses OS functionality - why do you need others? What is the idea?

Comment: @Rory , Regarding this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373080/saveas-a-file-and-move-it-s-icon-on-desktop-to-the-same-old-position-of-the-orig) , I need to find another method to rename a file , Because `Name` and `fso.MoveFile` have a possible behavior to move the file and I need imitate how Windows OS works when it rename a file ( like you use right-click and choose Rename)

Comment: @FunThomas ,Regarding this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373080/saveas-a-file-and-move-it-s-icon-on-desktop-to-the-same-old-position-of-the-orig) , I need to find another method to rename a file , Because `Name` and `fso.MoveFile` have a possible behavior to move the file and I need imitate how Windows OS works when it rename a file ( like you use right-click and choose Rename)

Comment: Have I read the other question correctly? You want to rename the file, but do not want the file's icon position on the desktop to change?

Comment: Have you tried `Ren` in DOS?

Comment: @CLR , yes you understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have easy methods to achieve what you want... Here is one more way which uses [SHFileOperation API](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SHFileOperation.shtml)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As LongPtr

Private Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = &H100
Private Const FO_RENAME = &H4

Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As LongPtr
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAborted As Boolean
    hNameMaps As LongPtr
    sProgress As String
End Type

Sub Sample()
    SHRenameFile "D:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test.xlsm", _
                 "D:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test2.xlsm"
End Sub

Public Sub SHRenameFile(ByVal strSource As String, ByVal strTarget As String)
    Dim op As SHFILEOPSTRUCT

    With op
        .wFunc = FO_RENAME
        .pTo = strTarget
        .pFrom = strSource
        .fFlags = FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS
    End With

    '~~> Perform operation
    SHFileOperation op
End Sub
```

Comment: Worth mentioning this method retains any file properties (read only etc) where the native VBA does not.

Comment: @KostasK. There are lot of wonderful things which this API offers. For example Windows Copy File Progress window and other things. But this API is an overkill if you just want to rename the file. The NAME method also retains file properties like "Read Only"

Comment: Agree. I got confused, the copy/move does not retain them, didn't know about the NAME. Thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: Your answer is great. The advantage of this API is I can **rename** a workbook **while it is still open** (sure after Change File Access to xlReadOnly) .
It has helped me with my own answer on this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373080/saveas-a-file-and-move-it-s-icon-on-desktop-to-the-same-old-position-of-the-orig)