# Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate alternative

Tags: excel, vba

I use this piece of code:

```
Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate
```

to activate a particular excel file, I notice that this method goes in error if the "File name extension" (in the View tab of the Folder Menu) is flagged.

In order to be independent of this, what modification should I do/include to the code or what alternative method should I use?

Comment: How is the workbook being opened? At that step, capture the workbook object so you can use it later, that way you don't have to worry about any of that. Also, think about why you need to activate it. There's generally no need to do that either - that just makes everything slow.

Comment: I interchange many times during the macro run between 2 workbooks, input and output excel files, and I need to activate the V_WBNameOutPut, to paste and elaborate, and this is done multiple times during the run. From the input file, I create the V_WBNameOutPut file.

Comment: Then it sounds like capturing the workbook object when you open it will work much better for you.

Comment: If you are talking about 'Hide extension for known file type', I can post a function able to return the respective key value. But I need to understand what does `V_WBNameOutPut` contain. Is it a name **containing extension or not**? Anyhow, it is not need to activate the workbook when you need pasting. Separate of that, even for pasting in not active workbook **you need to handle the workbook recognized workbook  name (with or without extension). If you clarify the boded first question I can supply a solution able to work in both situations, I think.

Comment: V_WBNameOutPut is a string, without Extention, like                            
``V_WBNameOutPut = "MyOutputFileName"``

Comment: Then, how would you open it in an environment having  'Hide extension for known file type' unchecked? What does `Debug.print Workbook(V_WBNameOutPut).FullName` return in `Immediate Window`? Is the extension shown? Do you like working with checked setting  'Hide extension for known file type'? I thought you have the extension included name, to make it working/being accepted in both variants... Otherwise, such an approach will not be able to work in the other environment, having the incriminated settings unchecked. As it is normally to be, for avoiding working blind.

Comment: So, answering your question, as it is formulated, you should use **the workbook name extension included** and I can supply a piece of code to make it able to work in both cases. There are cases when you may need working with "MyWB.xlsm" and "MyWB.xlsx".  even "MyWB.txt"... It would be complicated to differentiate them, without knowing their extension...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was talking about "File name extension", in the View tab of the Folder, if I de-flag this, than that part of code works. When use the Debug.print i receive the C:\....\MyOutputFileName.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the comment

> I interchange many times during the macro run between 2 workbooks, input and output
> excel files, and I need to activate the V_WBNameOutPut, to paste and elaborate, and > this is done multiple times during the run. From the input file, I create the > V_WBNameOutPut file.

As @brax said - capture the workbook when it's opened and you don't have to worry about the extension after that.

```
Sub Test()

    'Open the first workbook and store reference to it.
    Dim wrkBk1 As Workbook
    Set wrkBk1 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Darren Bartrup-Cook\Test 1.xlsx")
    
    'Open the second workbook and store reference to it.
    Dim wrkBk2 As Workbook
    Set wrkBk2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Darren Bartrup-Cook\Test 2.xlsx")
    
    'Copy/paste from wrkbk1 to wrkbk2.
    wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=wrkBk2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")
    
    'Create a new sheet in wrkbk2.
    Dim NewWrkSht As Worksheet
    Set NewWrkSht = wrkBk2.Worksheets.Add
    NewWrkSht.Name = "My New Sheet"
    
    'Paste copy/paste values from wrkbk1 to wrkbk2.
    wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Copy
    NewWrkSht.Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    'Make A3 in wrkbk2 equal the value in wrkbk1 A3.
    wrkBk2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = wrkBk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
    
    'Close the two workbooks.
    wrkBk2.Close SaveChanges:=True
    wrkBk1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What about the case of an **already open workbook** needing to be (re)processed? In case of 'Hide extension for known file type' `View` option being checked. I mean to set a workbook object based on its name... :)

Comment: If the workbook's open then `Set wrkbk = Workbooks("Test 1.xlsx")` works no matter the visibility of the extension, while `Set wrkbk = Workbooks("Test 1")` only works if the extension is hidden.

Comment: After installing a new OS, my first concern is to uncheck the incriminated `View` check box. So, I never tested in other circumstances, but from OP question I understood that `Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate` raises an error if the respective option is checked, using the workbook name without extension. So, using the name extension included it will work in both circumstances. As I said, I never tested anything having hidden extensions

Comment: Anyhow, I recently answered a question somehow related, needing to change the file name. Using `CreateObject("Shell.Application")` to change the file name, worked differently according to the invoked folder View settings. I mean, simple using extension included name, the extension was double. And the code needed to adapt the new name construction according to the registry key keeping this settings...

Comment: @FaneDuru - how did you determine the fix when using `Shell`?  Did you use the `Path` property (which always includes the extension) ?

Comment: @Tim Williams In a way... I used its name,  but the path was included. In fact, let me find the question in discussion and see the accepted answer... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373080/saveas-a-file-and-move-it-s-icon-on-desktop-to-the-same-old-position-of-the-orig/75418921#75418921), please.